# Can I do skewness on multiple standard deviation?

Tags: variance, standard-deviation, descriptive-statistics, skewness, kurtosis

I have a 1000 sample of an electrical test at each 4 different time, so I do simple descriptive statistic to obtain standard deviation at each 4 different time. Can I then use skewness on standard deviation itself to know if all my standard deviation is symmetrical? From my search, I only see people choose either one as a measure, not in a way that use both as I intended.

My idea is I want to see if the dispersion itself has any changes. I know ANOVA or F-test is another method can be considered by checking equality of variance, but it seem quite complex for technician to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the site. While you can certainly calculate the skewness of four numbers (whatever they may be, including standard deviations) with only four numbers you aren't going to get reliable estimates.

It's also not clear why you  want to know if the sds of the different samples are symmetric. You say you "want to see if the dispersion itself has any changes".  Skewness will not tell you that.

You could just look at the four numbers and try and see if there is a pattern. You could make a graph to help.  And, while you could try to model the change in SD using regression with SD as the DV and time as the IV, with only four values, you are, again, going to have unreliable estimates.

Even the usual test with ANOVA isn't very good. There's a quote that I only vaguely remember, something like "checking the equality of variances with ANOVA is like sending out a rowboat to see if it safe to launch a ship" (maybe someone knows the exact quote).

As for being too complex for a technician ... Well, often, you have to hire a statistician. Just like you often have to hire a doctor, or a lawyer, or some other professional.

Comment: Your idea of putting the standard deviation sample into regression make me think possibility of analyzing by standard error or maybe by sample variance of the standard deviation. Is it possible?

Comment: I think you really need to hire a consultant, so that you can discuss, in detail, what you want. Not me, I'm retired.